# Transition CSS3 not working in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to add fullscreen navigation area, i already made it, but the transition is not working, but another CSS code is working, what i missed here? is there something i need to add in somewhere when using angular2?

Here is my component folder looked like :
[image]

below is my css file, navbar.component.css :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

below is my html file, navbar.component.html :

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" *ngIf="displayNav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>


<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

below is my typescript file, navbar.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  public displayNav: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  openNav(){
    this.displayNav = true;
    console.log(this.displayNav);

  }

  closeNav(){
    this.displayNav = false;
    console.log(this.displayNav);
  }
}
```

when i click on ☰ open it just show the div area with id="myNav" without transition, i already set the transition in class="overlay"

```
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

but i try the transition in usual html with javascript n css, it work, what do i missed here?

Comment: can you add `!important` to your transition line and try.. i.e., `transition: 0.5s !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition isn't working because `*ngIf` removes the element from the DOM. You can achieve the desired effect in a few ways. Add and remove an active class on click with [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) or use [angular 2's animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html), particularly  `transition(* <=> void, animation(...))`.

I suggest the former because an element that should often disappear and reappear shouldn't use `*ngIf`.

If i got it right this is the only thing you need to change in your code:

HTML

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" [ngClass]="{active: displayNav}">
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
  ...
}

.overlay.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: i already tried your code, it's not working, when i click the button, nothing happened, i change my <div> area just like you told and i add .overlay . active